# WPF Selector -- How do I ensure that it's only going to allow a single selection and not multiple selections?

Tags: c#, wpf, selector, multi-select

Basically, I have a control that I want to extend from the [Selector Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.aspx). I know that Selector allows for multiple child items to be selected, but I don't want that. I only want a single child to be selected at a time.

Is there a setting that I'm not seeing in the Selector class that distinguishes between single/multi selections allowed, or is that something that is controlled by the class that I write that extends the Selector class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selector doesn't have support for multiple selections. ListBox, and therefore ListView, do support multiple selections.

In any event, you are responsible for the actual selection of items. Selector just exposes the properties and events that deal with selection.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the [MultiSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.multiselector.aspx)? It has a [CanSelectMultipleItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.multiselector.canselectmultipleitems.aspx) property that might help.

Comment: Genius! In order to have single select MultiSelector has to be chosen as base instead of the Selector. I like this answer, because basically the MultiSelector does only add the public access to CanSelectMultiple(Items) and no other redundant stuff.